# Targeting a whitespace before the linebreak with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, comments, whitespace

I want to strip comments after the symbol and the whitespace at the end of lines so my code is following like this

```
function solution(input, markers) {
   let regexp = new RegExp("["+ markers.join('') + "].*","gi")
   let removeWhiteSpace = input.replace(regexp,"")
   return removeWhiteSpace.replace(/\s+$/g,"")
};
```

I have a string like the following

> console.log(solution("apples, plums % and bananas\npears\noranges !applesauce",["%", "!"]))

I have trouble in targeting the whitespace after the "plums" without affecting the other white spaces. What can I improve in this regex to target that whitespace.

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you trying to remove the symbols in `markers` and strip any extra whitespace at the end of the string? Update your question.

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your comment. I should write the better form of question My question is solved by this regex - /\s[%!].*/gi

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is it matches everything after '%' or '!' and then replace whitespaces at the end of the string.
If you are trying to remove the symbols in markers and strip any extra whitespace at the end of the string then you can do that in one line of code:

```
let regex = /(?:[%!]+\s*|\s*$)/gm
input.replace(regex, "")
```

regex: /(?:[%!]+\s*|\s*$)/gm

```
(?:          Non capture group
  [%!]+\s*   zero or more spaces that follow one or more symbols (from marker var) 
  |          OR
   \s*$       zero or more spaces at the end of the input string
)
```

Comment: What I want to do is strip the words after the comment symbol so I think the code of mine work for me but what bothering me is the whitespaces left after the words before the new line. For the further clarification I am trying to solve this problem here [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd/train/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the whitespace you can try this code

```
function solution(input, markers) {
      const reg = new RegExp("["+ markers.join('') + "].*","gi")
      const lines = input.split('\n');
      const processedLines = lines.map(line => line.replace(reg, '').trim());
      return processedLines.join('\n');
    };
```

We remove comments and extra spaces from a text.